# Vue: how to know what text is selected / highlighted by user and display multiple instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to make component, `Highlight`, that can:

1. know what the user selected / highlighted (mousedown and drag over text)
2. show the highlighted text (color the aforementioned selected text in a color)
3. can handle multiple instances of this.

see images for idea of what I am aiming for:

[image: single-instance]

[image: multi-instance]

From google, StackExchange, Medium posts, etc I have a component which can figure out the text the user highlighted:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2340okq56p?fontsize=14)

This is mostly taken from this medium post by [freecodecamp](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-medium-like-highlight-menu-in-vue-dc515f2dddef), which uses a `slot` based approach.

For the actually rendering of highlighted text, most examples I have found do so via regex and replacing the original text with a span or something (e.g. [vue-text-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-text-highlight)).

These two methods are naturally at odd. It might work for highlighting once, but if the original text is altered to now contain a `span` element, then subsequent or re-selection won't work.

So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas to surmount this.

In the above images, I show what I will be using this highlight component for (linking two different textual instances), but for the moment I think the images clarify what I mean by selecting and highlighting text.

Comment: You're going to need to hold the state of the highlights. You'll then need to hold a state that links one highlight to one more other highlights, and colour code them similarly. I might have a crack at this shortly - seems fun

Comment: there you go, check out the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Was pretty fun - and this isn't a great attempt, but a quick one to get you going.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zw2179y2yl

It supports the following:

- Highlighting multiple bits of text independently with (relatively) random colours.
- Support for selecting text in the right panel (then click on the corresponding already highlighted text in the left box) and it will inherit the same colour.

Pretty easy to extend to set some ids on the arrays, and then hold references between the right and left boxes.

How to use:

- Action: Highlight some text on the left panel
- Result: You will see the highlighted text under the panels
- Action: Highlight some text on the right panel
- Result: It will show up with a grey background in the right panel
- Action: Click on one of the highlighted text rows under the panels
- Result: The text you previously highlighted on the right will inherit the colour of the selected text you clicked.

Edit:

Just noticed a couple of bugs:

- If you highlight a space, it totally screws up.
- The highlighting is greedy, so if you highlight "it", it will highlight all instances of "it" whether they are in words or not with the same colour throughout the whole text.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, it definitely is a jumping off point for me to get started. Yeah I noticed those too. It also prohibits highlighting previously highlighted text (e.g. "here is some text" and "s some text as an example", could not both be highlighted if "here is some text as an example" was the text body)

Comment: As mentioned, it's more to give you an idea of how you can get the two to operate together. What you're trying to achieve is actually pretty complex and will take quite a lot of time (days) to get right. Good luck

Comment: yup, nonetheless I really do appreciate your guidance. I'll leave the question unanswered for a little longer to see if anyone else wants to chime in :)

Comment: @SumNeuron - did you ever solve this? Care to add your solution?

Answer (score 2):

I kinda did the same thing (about grabbing user's selection) in my single file component [vue-selection-share](https://github.com/KnowsCount/vue-selection-share) when imitating medium's selection dropdown menu. This is what I did to grab the user's selection:

```js
const selection = window.getSelection()
```

and then, I used `startNode` and `endNode` to grab the elements that the selection starts and ends in:

```js
const startNode = selectionRange.startContainer.parentNode
const endNode = selectionRange.endContainer.parentNode
```

after I test whether the selection is valid, I transform it to a string

```js
this.selectedText = selection.toString()
```

whereafter creating a `handleAction` method using `this.selectedText`.

---

the random color-generation part can be solved simply by this below:

```js
data: {
    myColour: '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)
},
mounted() {
    document.body.style.background = this.myColour;
},
methods: {
    generator: function(){
        // give the selected text an ID before doing this
        let highlightedText = document.getElementById(highlightedText)
        this.myColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        document.highlightedText.style.background = this.myColour;
    }
}
```

you can, if I recall correctly, find more and `getElementById` and colour changing [here on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

I did not have the time to check the other answer but do follow his when you think his solution is better as my answer is a quick one written on my phone. during lunch.